# IntelliJ Idea 2019.2 crashing with NPW

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, ide

IntelliJ Idea 2019.2 crashing with below error, can someone please help me fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the support link provided?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the [third-party plug-ins folder](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) as described in the [support document](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007568559).